# Is there a convenient way to apply a lookup table to a large array in numpy?

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-2.x, lookup-tables

I’ve got an image read into numpy with quite a few pixels in my resulting array.

I calculated a lookup table with 256 values. Now I want to do the following:

```
for i in image.rows:
    for j in image.cols:
        mapped_image[i,j] = lut[image[i,j]]
```

Yep, that’s basically what a lut does.
Only problem is: I want to do it efficient and calling that loop in python will have me waiting for some seconds for it to finish.

I know of `numpy.vectorize()`, it’s simply a convenience function that calls the same python code.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992713/translate-every-element-in-numpy-array-according-to-key for the _reverse_ solution.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can just use `image` to index into `lut` if `lut` is **1D**.
Here's a starter on indexing in NumPy:
[http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c)

```
In [54]: lut = np.arange(10) * 10

In [55]: img = np.random.randint(0,9,size=(3,3))

In [56]: lut
Out[56]: array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])

In [57]: img
Out[57]: 
array([[2, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 0],
       [4, 3, 1]])

In [58]: lut[img]
Out[58]: 
array([[20, 20, 40],
       [10, 30,  0],
       [40, 30, 10]])
```

Mind also the indexing starts at `0`

Comment: *face-desk*
This is so simple, I could scream. I thought in the other direction the whole time and that it won’t work. But of course, numpy does things elementwise, so this is the obvious solution.  
Maybe I was too tired yesterday. ;)

Comment: Actually, it seems to work for for multi-dimensional LUTS as well, at least with numpy 1.9.2

Answer (score 33):

TheodrosZelleke's answer in correct, but I just wanted to add a little undocumented wisdom to it. Numpy provides a function, `np.take`, which according to the documentation *"does the same thing as fancy indexing."*

Well, almost, but not quite the same:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lut = np.arange(256)
>>> image = np.random.randint(256, size=(5000, 5000))
>>> np.all(lut[image] == np.take(lut, image))
True
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('lut[image]',
...               'from __main__ import lut, image', number=10)
4.369504285407089
>>> timeit.timeit('np.take(lut, image)',
...               'from __main__ import np, lut, image', number=10)
1.3678052776554637
```

`np.take` is about 3x faster! In my experience, when using 3D luts to convert images from RGB to other color spaces, adding logic to convert the 3D look-up to a 1D flattened look-up allows a x10 speed up.

Comment: Oh, wow, I looked deeper into `np.put` for a while because I thought this might work. When it didn’t I didn’t check the other functions. -.-

Comment: These timings are two years old now: newer versions of NumPy, starting with 1.9, have a much improved fancy indexing machinery, which is now comparably as fast as using `take`.

Comment: It seems `lut[image]` is now (NumPy 1.20) more than twice faster than `np.take(lut, image)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are limited to using numpy, [TheodrosZelleke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14448935/12808884) is the way to go.  But if you allow other modules, `cv2` is a useful module for interacting with image data, and it accepts numpy arrays as input.  A big limitation is that the image array must have `dtype='uint8'`, but as long as that is OK, the function `cv2.LUT` does exactly what we want, and it provides a significant speedup:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cv2
>>> lut = np.arange(256, dtype='uint8')
>>> image = np.random.randint(256, size=(5000, 5000), dtype='uint8')
>>> np.all(lut[image] == cv2.LUT(image, lut))
True
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('lut[image]', 'from __main__ import lut, image', number=10)
0.5747578000000431
>>> timeit.timeit('cv2.LUT(image, lut)', 
...               'from __main__ import cv2, lut, image', number=10)
0.07559149999997317
```

Your lookup table can be some other datatype, but you loose a lot of the speed improvement (although numpy indexing takes a performance hit as well).  For example, with `dtype='float64'`:

```
>>> lut = np.arange(256, dtype='float64')
>>> timeit.timeit('lut[image]', 'from __main__ import lut, image', number=10)
1.068468699999812
>>> timeit.timeit('cv2.LUT(image, lut)', 
...               'from __main__ import cv2, lut, image', number=10)
0.41085720000000947
```