# Vectorizing a sum over a function of unordered pairs?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'd like to sum a function f over unordered pairs (n,m) with n and m distinct, where n,m range from -N to N.

The function depends on a sequence of floats stored in a dictionary, indexed from -N to N. It looks something like:

```
def f(n,m):
    return dict[n]*dict[m]*np.sin(c*(n-m)) / (n-m)
```

Naively, I'd write:

```
indices = [ (n,m) for n in range(-N,N+1) for m in range(-N,N+1) if m>n ]
sum([f(n,m) for (n,m) in indices])
```

Is there a way to vectorize this with numpy and make it more efficient? I'm using Python 3, in case it matters.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the pairs are unordered?  It looks like your function indeed depends on the order of `n` and `m`.

Comment: Add sample input, output and explain how the code works through to get to the output?

Comment: Also, if `n` is a scalar, `dict[n]` would throw an error, right?

Comment: @BrenBarn: sin is an odd function, so the sign change from flipping n,m inside the sin cancels the sign change from flipping n,m in (n-m).

Comment: @Divakar: Sorry, I don't understand why there'd be an error. The keys to a dictionary can be integers.

Comment: @daunpunk: Ah, I didn't read carefully enough.  Anyway, you could look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992713/translate-every-element-in-numpy-array-according-to-key).  If you can vectorize the dict lookups the rest should be easy.

Comment: I think adding a sample input would make it more clear.