# filter pandas dataframe using function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a pandas dataframe `df` with columns `A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H`, and I want to filter the dataframe using a function `functn` that takes in a "row" and returns true or false based on if the row fulfills certain conditions (lets say the function uses every column except for `H`). Is there a way to efficiently filter this dataframe without a long and ugly lambda? The solution I have so far looks like this:

```
df = df[df.apply(functn, axis=1)]
```

but this method seems to be VERY slow, even for a frame with 15k lines. Is there a clean and efficient way to filter a pandas dataframe using a user defined python function instead of a lambda or query?

note: I previously implemented this using plain python 2d arrays and it was MUCH faster than using pandas. Am I misusing a certain feature or not aware of a way to make this filtering process faster?

edit:

The data is structured roughly like this:

```
#       A       B       C     D     E     F      G        H      
[
    [string1, string2, int1, int2, int3, int4, float1, float2], 
    ...
]
```

The function does something like this:

```
def filter(row):
    var1 = row.G <= 0.01
    partial_a = (((row.D - row.C + 1)*1.0)/global_map[row.A])
    partial_b = (((row.F - row.E + 1)*1.0)/global_map[row.B])
    partial = partial_a >= 0.66 or partial_b >= 0.66
    return var1 and partial
```

The non-pandas implementation basically took the dataframe, which if not in pandas form was basically a 2d array, and looped through each element, applied the function to it (except the argument was a list instead of a "row"), and if it returned true, added that new element to another list.

Comment: It'll be easier to help you if you can provide (a) example data, (b) the details of `fucntn`, and (c) the non-Pandas implementation you used.  As is, it's hard to know where your bottleneck is.  (Benchmarking data would be nice too.)

Comment: I'll edit the original post to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: @andrew_reece it should be updated!

Comment: Looking on your filter() apply function, I have noticed that you compute the global_map for each row. Is this computation time-efficient? Otherwise the apply function will calculate the global_map[row.A] and global_map[row.B] for each row..Therefore to speed up processing time you should had pre-computed these values (global_map[row.A] and global_map[row.B]) before the filter() and then pass them to filter() function as arguments. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you don't need a function.  Let's use boolean indexing as follows:

```
cond1 = df['G'] <= 0.01
cond2 = (((df.D - df.C + 1)*1.0)/global_map[df.A]) >= 0.66
cond3 = (((df.F - df.E + 1)*1.0)/global_map[df.B]) >= 0.66

mask = cond1 & (cond2 | cond3)

df[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks! As a followup, is there a way to generalize this mask such that I can apply it to other dataframes? I think this is specific since it references the one `df` I mentioned.

Comment: If `global_map` is a dict, you might need to vectorize the lookup, something like `np.vectorize(global_map.get)(df.A)`

Comment: You should be able to write that as a function to generate mask then apply the mask to the dataframe without looping.

Comment: @andrew_reece true that's a good point.

scott, yeah I'll try that

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it.  I created a function genMask(df) return mask, then I did `df1[genMask(df1)]`.  It should work.

Comment: @andrew_reece is there a reason the dict has to be vectorized? I noticed I got an error if it wasn't. Is that because the mask is applied on all elements or something like that?

Comment: dicts are basically just lookup tables, they're not used to having a whole bunch of keys crammed into a single lookup.  have a look at this post for more options: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16992713/2799941

Comment: @Swarage What sort of increase in speed did you achieve, I am curious?

Comment: @ScottBoston it went from taking 3.894 seconds to 0.376 seconds for the entire python program, so roughly a 10x speedup.