# Ordinal Categorical Data in Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I have a dataset with categorical data that are of different weights, take for an instance Phd has a higher weight than Masters and like MSc is higher than Bsc.

I know am to use Label encoder but i dont want python to assigned codes to these variables arbitrarily. I want higher codes for Phd = 4, Msc = 3 , Bsc = 2, O Levels = 1 and No education = 0.

Is there anyway i can go about this? Can anyone be of help?

Comment: Is your data in a Pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

LabelEncoder will encode the categories based on alphabetic order and stored in `classes_` attribute. By default this is the case:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(['Phd', 'Msc','Bsc', 'O Levels','No education'])
ll.classes_
# Output: array(['Bsc', 'Msc', 'No education', 'O Levels', 'Phd'], dtype='|S12')
```

How many categories are there? If less, you can yourself do the conversion by using a dict, similar to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16992783/3374996):

```
my_dict = {'Phd':4, 'Msc':3 , 'Bsc':2, 'O Levels':1, 'No education':0}

y = ['No education', 'O Levels','Bsc', 'Msc','Phd']
np.vectorize(my_dict.get)(y)

# Output: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```