# Is there a Numpy equivalent to string `translate`?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a string

```
>>> s = "abcdef"
```

I can replace more than one character with

```
>>> s.translate(str.maketrans("abc", "xyz"))
xyzdef
```

Is there a function that replicates this behavior in Numpy? i.e. some `func` such that

```
>>> np.func(arr, mapping)
mapped_array
```

This functionality can be implemented as

```
def func(arr, mapping):
    new_arr = arr.copy()
    for k, v in mapping.items():
        new_arr[new_arr == k] = v
    return new_arr
```

But this will be very slow for large arrays and/or large mappings.

Comment: I'd say it's not the same the difference being "every element" in the linked question as opposed to only those elements that correspond to a key in the mapping as is implicit in this question. Any objections?

Comment: I think the proposed duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992713/translate-every-element-in-numpy-array-according-to-key is not good.  Despite the name, it's really about using a dictionary to replace elements of an array; IOW using a dictionary as an array mapping.  I'm going to reopen this.

Comment: Isn't this supported this as `mapping[arr]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `translate` is a string operation.  `np.char` has a bunch of functions that apply such methods to all elements of a string dtype array:

```
In [7]: s = "abcdef"
In [8]: arr = np.array([[s,s,s],[s,s,s]])
In [9]: arr
Out[9]: 
array([['abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef'],
       ['abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef']], dtype='<U6')
In [10]: np.char.translate(arr, str.maketrans("abc", "xyz"))
Out[10]: 
array([['xyzdef', 'xyzdef', 'xyzdef'],
       ['xyzdef', 'xyzdef', 'xyzdef']], dtype='<U6')
```

However, because it calls string methods, it is not particularly fast.  Past tests have shown the functions to be about the same speed as explicit loops.

If there were a limited number of such replacements, you could use one of the mapping methods in the proposed duplicate.  But if you want to full power of `str.translate`, this, or some iteration, is the best you can do.  `numpy` does not implement string operations in compiled code.

`frompyfunc` is a good way of applying a function to all elements of an array.  It tends to be modestly faster than more explicit loops:

```
In [11]: np.frompyfunc(lambda s: s.translate(str.maketrans("abc", "xyz")),1,1)(arr)
Out[11]: 
array([['xyzdef', 'xyzdef', 'xyzdef'],
       ['xyzdef', 'xyzdef', 'xyzdef']], dtype=object)
In [12]: _.astype('U6')
Out[12]: 
array([['xyzdef', 'xyzdef', 'xyzdef'],
       ['xyzdef', 'xyzdef', 'xyzdef']], dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: I recently had the need to demonstrate these general trends [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/b6509486c9333db11b0eac78e7bc297c). I compared working with numpy arrays vs python `list` objects for performing string-like operations using `fromfunc`, not exactly equivalent because we are *starting* with `numpy.ndarray` of numeric types, I suspect if they were `object` type arrays it would be even worse.

Answer (score 1):

There is no dictionary in numpy, so no direct equivalent mechanism.

if  "keys" are in a short range (like Unicode characters), you can build a lookup table to replace some keys, using indexing techniques for fast replacement :

```
data = np.random.randint(0, 256, 10)
# [179 111 211 147 204  11  20  38  87 230]

lookup_table = np.arange(256) 
lookup_table[[11, 20]] = [0, 1] # mapping

lookup_table[data]
# [179 111 211 147 204   0   1  38  87 230]
```