# How do I change id values in a numpy array to a string numpy array with a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I'm working on a script that converts ids of school names to actual school names structured in a numpy array.

For example

```
[[1,2,3],[3,6,7]]
```

becomes

```
[[school-a,school-b,school-c],[school-c,school-f,school-g]
```

The school and ids sit together in a python dictionary.

I've tried doing this:

```
for x in np.nditer(finalarray, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    x[...] = school_ids.get(int(x))
    print(school_ids.get(int(x)))
print(finalarray)
```

but that gave the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'school-a'
```

it's important that the structure of the numpy array stays the same, because I also thought of just iterating every item, but then the structure is lost.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using a numpy array for this? Why don't you just use python lists?

Comment: The array is generated via numpy

Comment: `finalarray` is a `dtype` integer array.  The `x[...]=...` step tries to convert the string (from the dictionary) to an integer so it can put it in `finalarray`.  You want a new string dtype array, not a rewrite of the original.    `nditer` is not a good tool for beginners.  It's too complicated, and doesn't offer any speed advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992713/translate-every-element-in-numpy-array-according-to-key):

```
x = np.array([[1,1,3], [2,2,2]])
d = {1: 'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
np.vectorize(d.get)(x)
>> array([['a', 'a', 'c'],
   ['b', 'b', 'b']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: It is mentioned both in the question title and the post itself that the ids map to the school IDs from a dictionary. It's quite possible that the alignment with indices is purely coincidental; this isn't what the OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

suppose I have a dict :

```
dictt = {
    0: 'school-a',
    1: 'school-b',
    2: 'school-c',
    3: 'school-d',
    4: 'school-e',
    5: 'school-f',
    6: 'school-g',
    7: 'school-h',
    8: 'school-i'
}

_ids = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,6,7]])
school_ids = np.array(list(dictt.values()))
print school_ids[_ids-1]
```

got:

```
[['school-a' 'school-b' 'school-c']
 ['school-c' 'school-f' 'school-g']]
```

Comment: The OP clearly says that they have a dictionary of `{'id': 'school'}`, not an array

Comment: sorry for miss out those.
how about 
    school_ids = np.array(list(dictt.values()))
?

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for either. They are asking for a mapping of values in the dictionary to the array