# Need help in if loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm new to python coding and I do have the below simple **list** in my code.

`Marks = [82,70,60,50,40,30]`

Now my requirement is I want to get another column in my output called **Result** as below

[image]

So how to use **if** and **else** to achieve the output which i'm looking like

```py
if Marks > 80 print 'Distinction'
if Marks >60 and Marks <= 70 print 'Grade A'
if Marks >50 and Marks <= 60 print 'Grade B'
if Marks >40 and Marks <= 50 print 'Grade C'
else print 'Good for Nothing'
```

Comment: See if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16992783/4985099

Comment: @Sushanth Couldn't get that from the link you provided.

Comment: Change your title to the problem you are facing.

Comment: Why **if-else**? You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) try this `pd.cut(df['Marks'], [0,40, 50, 60, 70, 100],labels=['Good for nothing', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'Distinction'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Marks = [82,70,60,50,40,30]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Marks' : Marks})
print(df)

def a(b):
if b['Marks'] > 80:
    return 'Distinction'
elif b['Marks'] > 69:
    return 'Grade A'
elif b['Marks'] > 59:
    return 'Grade B'
elif b['Marks'] > 49:
    return 'Grade C'
else:
    return 'Good for Nothing'

df['Result'] = df.apply(a, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Using Def & Return

Comment: don't forget to indent the body of your function :)

Answer (score 3):

this is a good task for `np.where`:

```
df['Result'] = 'Good for Nothing'
df['Result'] = np.where((df['Marks'] > 80), 'Distinction', df['Result'])
df['Result'] = np.where((df['Marks'] > 60) & (df['Marks'] <= 70), 'Grade A', df['Result'])
df['Result'] = np.where((df['Marks'] > 50) & (df['Marks'] <= 60), 'Grade B', df['Result'])
df['Result'] = np.where((df['Marks'] > 40) & (df['Marks'] <= 50), 'Grade C', df['Result'])
```

Comment: can this be achieved with if else statement?

Comment: `np.select` and `np.where` will be similar performance-wise. @Vikas there is no optimal way in pandas to use the words `if` or `else` in a situation like this. `np.where` is similar to an excel if, then statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in Python3

```py
Marks = [82,70,60,50,40,30]

for i in Marks: 
    if i > 80:
        print('Distinction')
    elif i >60 and i <= 70:
        print('Grade A')
    elif i >50 and i <= 60:
        print('Grade B')
    elif i >40 and i <= 50:
        print('Grade C')
    else:
        print('Good for Nothing')
```

Comment: thanks for that. How do i get the both the columns **Marks** and **Result** from the above output which i'm expecting?

Comment: This is a great answer for how to print out the results in the terminal Josh, but I think the OP needs to get this in a dataframe.