# Order one array based on the order of the other array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

2 numpy arrays have the exact same values.

> arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

> arr2 = np.array([2,3,1,5,4])

How can I order the values in the first array the way they are ordered in the second array?

Comment: Do you want arr2 to be in ascending order?

Comment: @Hamza usman ghani No I need arr1 to be reordered the way arr2 is

Comment: You're getting in to a philosophical issue here: would `arr2 = np.array(arr1)` be acceptable?

Comment: @chepner in the real dataset arr1 has other values attached to it, so they will need to be reordered accordingly

Comment: You need a clearer example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the np.vectorize method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16992783/15565369)

```
map_dict = {x[0]:x[1] for x in zip(arr1, arr2)}

mapped_array = np.vectorize(map_dict.get)(arr1)
```

Comment: @Hamza no, arr2 is not an example of the desirable output, it exists in a separate dataset

Comment: @Hamza That's a bit of an assumption. It seems that this is a one-to-one mapping problem