# Relabel multiple values in 2D numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an image (segmentation map) which can be simplified to the following:

```py
import numpy as np

x, y = np.indices((80, 80))
x1, y1, x2, y2 = 28, 28, 44, 52
r1, r2 = 16, 20
mask_circle1 = (x - x1) ** 2 + (y - y1) ** 2 < r1 ** 2
mask_circle2 = (x - x2) ** 2 + (y - y2) ** 2 < r2 ** 2
image = np.max([mask_circle1, mask_circle2*2], axis=0)
```

This `image` contains two circles labeled 1 and 2 respectively. I now want to relabel all values according to a `old_value : new_value` map / dictionary I have.

```py
relabels = {1: 7, 2: 3}
```

The naive solution to this problem would be the following:

```py
labels = []
for old_val, new_val in relabels.items():
    labels.append(np.where(image==old_val, new_val, 0))
new_image = np.max(labels, axis=0)
```

This works flawlessly but is rather slow when scaled to larger arrays with more labels. Is there any way to vectorise this operation instead of processing all relabelling steps one by one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could probably toss the old circles and draw new ones using cv2.circle

Comment: I had to create an example - the real segmaps are irregularly shaped and can't be drawn with circle

Answer (score 1):

You can use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for elementwise comparison followed by multiplying with new labels and then reducing by taking `max()` along axis `0`:

```py
import numpy as np
old_labels = np.array([1, 2])
new_labels = np.array([3, 7])

# generating some random image with entries 0, 1 and 2
image = np.random.randint(0, 3, (10, 10))
# transform labels 
new_image = ((image == old_labels[:, None, None]).astype(int) * new_labels[:, None, None]).max(axis = 0)
```

**Sample I/O**:

```py
>>> image = np.random.randint(0, 3, (10, 10))
>>> image
 array([[2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2],
        [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2],
        [0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1],
        [2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
        [1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])

>>> new_image = ((image == old_labels[:, None, None]).astype(int) * new_labels[:, None, None]).max(axis = 0)
>>> new_image
 array([[7, 7, 7, 3, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [3, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 7, 7, 3, 7],
        [3, 7, 7, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 3, 7],
        [3, 7, 0, 0, 7, 7, 3, 3, 0, 7],
        [0, 3, 7, 3, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7],
        [0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7],
        [0, 7, 3, 7, 7, 3, 0, 7, 0, 3],
        [3, 0, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3],
        [7, 0, 7, 7, 3, 7, 0, 7, 0, 7],
        [3, 0, 0, 7, 3, 3, 7, 0, 3, 7]])
```

Note that here the label `0` stays the same before and after transformation. Since you did not have `0` in the dictionary `relabels` I assumed it stays the same. Otherwise just put `0` in the array `old_labels` and its corresponding new label in `new_labels`.

Answer (score 0):

I found an even faster option that is slightly modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992713/translate-every-element-in-numpy-array-according-to-key):

```py
import numpy as np

# Replace values
new_image = np.vectorize(relabels.get)(image)

# Replace None / undefined in relabel
new_image = np.where(new_image == None, 0, new_image).astype(int)
```