# Adjusting contrast of image purely with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying write a contrast adjustment for images  in gray scale colors but couldn't find the right way to do it so far. This is what I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from scipy import misc
def fix_contrast(image):
    minimumColor = np.amin(image)
    maximumColor = np.amax(image)
    #avg = (minimumColor - maximumColor)/2 first attempt
    avg = np.mean(image) #second attempt
    colorDownMatrix = image < avg # also tried
    colorUpMatrix = image > avg 
    #also tried:   colorUpMatrix = image > avg * 1.2
    # and : colorDownMatrix = image < avg* 0.3

    image = image - minimumColor*colorDownMatrix
    image = image + maximumColor*colorUpMatrix
    lessThen0 = image<0
    moreThen255 = image>255
    image[lessThen0] = 0
    image[moreThen255] = 255
    return image
```

My general attempt was to decrease elements towards 0 the pixels that their are "closer" to 0 and to increase elements towards 255 the elements that are "closer" to 255. I tried to measure closeness by mean function but before that by the arithmetic average, but all my attempts didn't get me to any good result.

the image I am working on :
[image]

the result I am aiming for:
[image: goal picture]

Am I anywhere close to the solution? Any hints/ tips will be great

Comment: Can you have a floating point intermediate representation of the image? Then just do something like `np.round((image - minimum) / (maximum - minimum) * 255)`.

Comment: For what it is worth, DataCamp has a great tutorial on this that goes into much greater depth on the technical aspects of the process.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in my, though the point here is to get better understanding in numpy so pure numpy it is

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm learning Python and `numpy` and thought I'd try to implement a *"LookUp Table"* (LUT). It works, and the output image has the full range from black to white, but I'm happy to receive suggestions for improvement.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open the input image as numpy array, convert to greyscale and drop alpha
npImage=np.array(Image.open("cartoon.png").convert("L"))

# Get brightness range - i.e. darkest and lightest pixels
min=np.min(npImage)        # result=144
max=np.max(npImage)        # result=216

# Make a LUT (Look-Up Table) to translate image values
LUT=np.zeros(256,dtype=np.uint8)
LUT[min:max+1]=np.linspace(start=0,stop=255,num=(max-min)+1,endpoint=True,dtype=np.uint8)

# Apply LUT and save resulting image
Image.fromarray(LUT[npImage]).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to increase the contrast (i.e. pull apart darker and brighter pixels), is just to "stretch out" the current existing range (144 to 216) over the entire spectrum (0 to 255):

Setup, same way as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50602577/704371).

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

pixvals = np.array(Image.open("image.png").convert("L"))
```

And then expand the range

```py
pixvals = ((pixvals - pixvals.min()) / (pixvals.max()-pixvals.min())) * 255
Image.fromarray(pixvals.astype(np.uint8))
```

The result is effectively the same as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50602577/704371), just with slightly less code:
[image]

Now, in this image, that might be enough. However some images might have a few pixels that are really close to 0 or 255, which would render this method ineffective.

Here [`numpy.percentile()`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) comes to the rescue. The idea is to "clip" the range in which pixels are allowed to exist.

```py
minval = np.percentile(pixvals, 2)
maxval = np.percentile(pixvals, 98)
pixvals = np.clip(pixvals, minval, maxval)
pixvals = ((pixvals - minval) / (maxval - minval)) * 255
Image.fromarray(pixvals.astype(np.uint8))
```

Which results in a little bit higher contrast, since all values below 2% and above 98% are effectively removed. (Play with these values as you see fit) 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply a mapping curve like this:

[image: contrast]

It makes the dark tones darker, the light tones lighter, and increases the range of the medium shades.

To achieve that, I'd find the minimum and maximum, then create a lookup table that expands the narrow remaining range into a whole range between 0 and 255. After that, I'd [apply the lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14448935/223424).

This will certainly leave some blocking, because the ranges of nice gradients of the source were compressed in a lossy way. To fix it, you might consider applying a "smart blur" algorithm that blurs only pixels that have low contrast between them, and does not touch those with high contrast. (I don't see a nice link with a numpy-friendly algorithm, though).

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use numpy. This codes a bit slow but helps.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("cartoon.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
imgAdjusted = img.copy()
height, width, _ = img.shape

max = img.max()
min = img.min()


for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        calculate = lambda pixel: ((pixel - min) / (max - min)) * 255
        imgAdjusted[j, i] = calculate(img[j,i])


plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.title("Original")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.title("Adjusted")
plt.imshow(imgAdjusted)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You may need auto transforms using Tensroflows!

```
image = plt.imread('F:\\temp\\20220117\\GO48R.png')
model_normalize = tf.keras.models.Sequential([  
            tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(256, 256)),
            tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
            tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),])

predictions_red = model_normalize.predict(np.reshape(red, (1, 128, 128)))
predictions_green = model_normalize.predict(np.reshape(green, (1, 128, 128)))
predictions_blue = model_normalize.predict(np.reshape(blue, (1, 128, 128))) 
    
predictions = np.ones((128, 128, 3)) - 1
predictions[:,:,0] = predictions_red
predictions[:,:,1] = predictions_blue
predictions[:,:,2] = predictions_green

predictions = np.reshape(predictions, (128,128,3))
predictions = ( predictions - np.min(predictions) ) * 10
plt.figure(figsize=(1,2))
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(predictions)
plt.xlabel('predictions')
    
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.xlabel('image')
    
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: As someone asking about blur and contrast: Normalized and Contrast]

[image: Without Networks it contrast all]