# Replacing index numbers of a list according to another list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

The list `A` is based on list `T1`. Now `T1` is transformed to list `T2`. I want to replace the index numbers of list `A` with respect to `T2` i.e. element `1` is to be replaced with `2`, `2` is to be replaced with `4`, `3` is to be replaced with `5`. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

T1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
A=[np.array([[[0, 1],
        [0, 3],
        [1, 3],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 5],
        [4, 7],
        [5, 7],
        [6, 4]]])]

T2 = [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

The expected output is

```
A=[array([[[0, 2],
        [0, 5],
        [2, 5],
        [5, 8],
        [5, 10],
        [8, 9],
        [8, 11],
        [9, 11],
        [10, 8]]])]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Let me make sure I understand the problem correctly. The idea is: because `T2` has the value `2` in the same position where `T1` has the value `1`, therefore every `1` in the `A` array should be replaced with `2`?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448763 answer your question?

Comment: That's right. Basically, there's one-to-one correspondence between ```T1``` and ```T2``` i.e. all ```1``` is to be replaced with ```2```, all ```2``` to be replaced with ```4``` and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work for any arrays `T1`, `T2` and `A`, where `T1` and `T2` have the same length and any value in `A` can be found in `T1`. First we create a dictionary where each value in `T1` is mapped to the value at the same index in `T2`. After that we replace all the values in `A` with the ones they map to.

```
def general(T1, T2, A):
    tmp = A[0][0]
    map = dict(zip(T1, T2))

    for i in range(0, len(tmp)):
        pair = tmp[i]
        pair[0] = map[pair[0]]
        pair[1] = map[pair[1]]
    return A
```

For the specific example it is not necessary to create the dictionary. Since `T1` already contains the index of the value to use in `T2`, we can replace the values in `A` directly.

```
def specific(T2, A):
    tmp = A[0][0]
    for i in range(0, len(tmp)):
        pair = tmp[i]
        pair[0] = T2[pair[0]]
        pair[1] = T2[pair[1]]
    return A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zip_dict = dict(zip(T1, T2))
B = [np.array([[list(map(lambda x: zip_dict[x],list(i))) for i in A[0][0]]])]
```